# React native onPress with TouchableWithoutFeedback is not working

Tags: react-native, touchablewithoutfeedback

I am developing a simple React Native application for learning purpose. I am just taking my initial step to get into the React Native world. But in this very early stage, I am having problems. I cannot get a simple touch event working. I am implementing touch event using TouchableWithoutFeedback. This is my code.

```
class AlbumList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            displayList : true
        }
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchAlbums();
    }

    albumPressed(album)
    {
        console.log("Touch event triggered")
    }

    renderAlbumItem = ({item: album}) => {
        return (
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.albumPressed.bind(this)}>
                    <Card>
                        <CardSection>
                            <Text>{album.artist}</Text>
                        </CardSection>
                        <CardSection>
                            <Text>{album.title}</Text>
                        </CardSection>
                    </Card>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            )
    }

    render() {
        let list;
        if (this.state.displayList) {
            list = <FlatList
                data={this.props.albums}
                renderItem={this.renderAlbumItem}
                keyExtractor={(album) => album.title}
            />
        }

        return (
            list
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return state.albumList;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        fetchAlbums : AlbumListActions.fetchAlbums
    }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AlbumList);
```

As you can see, I am implementing touch event on the list item. But it is not triggering at all when I click on the card on Simulator. Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: There is no issue with the code. is there any errors or warning ?

Comment: Are you on debug mode ? and arent you seeing anything in the console ?

Comment: I changed to show alert. Not triggered. If I used TouchableHighlight, it works.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10180#issuecomment-298375648

Comment: TouchableWithoutFeedback is just bad, IMO. Doesn't work for no reason sometimes, doesn't use the same API as the other touchables. Requires a single view as a child for no reason, doesn't support absolute positioning. Like, why?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should wrap your content in  component like this:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback>
 <View>
  <Your components...>
 </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: The [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10180#issuecomment-298375648) has already been discussed in the comments. Perhaps you can fill in the other details so it's all in one place. Simply posting a code snippet without an explanation is rarely helpful.

Comment: I have to search first for any issue or errors instead of figuring out by myself and wasting huge time on small things. which already has been known issues.... by the why thanks for posting this answer.

Answer (score 32):

`TouchableWithoutFeedback` always needs to have child `View` component. So a component that composes a `View` isn't enough.

So instead of

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={...} onPressOut={...} onPress={...}>
  <MyCustomComponent />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

use:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={...} onPressOut={...} onPress={...}>
  <View>
    <MyCustomComponent />
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

See the [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10180#issuecomment-298375648) for more info

Answer (score 14):

Can be used with `<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1.0}> </TouchableOpacity>`

Comment: Better solution IMO

Answer (score 4):

In more recent React Native versions, just use Pressable instead:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable

Answer (score 2):

For those who struggle with this issue in react-native 0.64, and wrapping it in just a View doesn't work, try this:

```js
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
    <View pointerEvents="none">
      <Text>Text</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The pointerEvents="none" helped me to solve a particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i accidentally imported TouchableWithoutFeedback from react-native-web instead of react-native. After importing from react-native everything worked as expected.

Comment: I imported it form `react-native-gesture-handler`, you saved at least 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reasons, even wrapping the children in a `View` inside the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` wasn't working for me. What fixed it for me is replacing `TouchableWithoutFeedback` with the new `Pressable` component introduced in 2020.

Also wrapping the child with a `View` or wrapping the whole `TouchableWithoutFeedback` with another `View` or setting the `pointerEvents="none"` of the inner `View` as suggested by other users seems like workarounds.

For me the new component: `Pressable` seems like a good choice to replace the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` component, it also offers a lot of [versatility](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-native-touchable-vs-pressable-components/) if you need.

So, using Pressable, the code in the question can be modified like so:

```js
<Pressable onPress={this.albumPressed.bind(this)}>
  <Card>
    <CardSection>
      <Text>{album.artist}</Text>
    </CardSection>
    <CardSection>
      <Text>{album.title}</Text>
    </CardSection>
  </Card>
</Pressable>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, there was a shadow underneath, which caused instability. What I did to solve it was quite simple: zIndex: 65000

```
<View style={{ zIndex: 65000 }}>
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={() =>  {}>
     <View>
     </View>
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</View>
```